# What test in R check whether the variance of the error term is constant or not for time series model?

Tags: r, time-series

I saw people test it by plotting the residual term and its histogram. I wonder if there is a method in R that does the test. Thank you.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on stackExchange. I did not know the rule. I think I am actually looking for more info about the term heteroskedasticity that Sympa mentioned, and I will read more about it. This is too new to me.

Comment: That's OK. Just edit your question to focus more on the statistical issue you are wondering about. It's fine to mention R as well. You just don't want the whole of your question to be "is there a method in R to do this".

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially testing residuals for heteroskedasticity.  In R, you can code the Breusch Pagan test (main heteroskedasticity test) using the lmtest package and the bptest () function.  You can also use the car package and code the same Breusch Pagan test with the ncvTest () function.